# using string in other method

Tags: c#, wpf, string

i have the following code. i need to do this:

```
public void Window1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   opendirectory();
}

public void opendirectory()
{
    Stream checkStream = null;
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

     openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;    

     if ((bool)openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
     {
          try
          {
                if ((checkStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    // i need the following code to be stored as a string
                    string antcbatchlocation = openFileDialog.FileName;                   
                }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
                {
                        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Problem occured, try again later");
            }
        }
```

then i will use that string in a later button event:

```
public void BuildButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process runantc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            runantc.StartInfo.FileName = antcbatchlocation;
        }
```

Perhaps something is wrong with this string as a variable. Seems to be like string antcbatchlocation is declared local variable. If so how should i go about fixing it? Please help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your string as a private member of your `Window1` class, rather than a local variable in your `opendirectory` method. Then, in your button click method, simply check to make sure your string is not null, so you know the user has gone through your dialog and selected a file first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an instance variable. That means that it's a variable that is local to the class instance (in this case `Window1). This also means that it's accessible to any method inside that class instance.

Add this line of code in your class declreation, just above the `public Window1(){}` constructor.

`private string _BatchLocation;`

then inside the `opendirectory()` method, instead of creating a local string variable, set the `openFileDialog.FileName` to this instance variable.

`_BatchLocation = openFileDialog.FileName;`

you can then access this in the click event handler... thus your code will look like this:

`runantc.StartInfo.FileName = _BatchLocation`;

Have a look at this post for more information: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/anandctutorials/article.php/c5829